# Call Main Activity using an Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Is it possible to recall the main activity from another activity using an intent? I tried running the code below (the main Activity is ImageSelection):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,ImageSelection.class);

  switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
      startActivity(intent);    
  } 
}
```

Comment: and what happened?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the correct way to start the `ImageSelection` activity.

If you'd like to bring a previous `ImageSelection` to the front or clear the Activities on top of it, try one of the [Intent flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

or:

```
intent.setFLAGS(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BRING_TO_FRONT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead of your `onClick()` class:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageSelection.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```